# About complex limits for integration of real functions

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I have come across an integral equation, 
$\tag{1} \int_{0}^i\,(\sin⁡ x )^p (\cos ⁡x )^q dx,\;i=\sqrt{-1}\label{1}$

I know the solution of the equation,

$\tag{2} \int_{0}^i\,(\sin⁡ x )^p (\cos ⁡x )^q dx\label{2},$

Can I, simply substitute i in place of a for the solution of the integral equation \eqref{2}, and would that be the solution of the integral equation \eqref{1} ?
I am not integrating over any particular plane or something. This equation has been arrived at in a differential equation, and a particular substitution, in that integral equation, makes the limit as i. 
I will eagerly wait for your reply.

Comment: what is this ▒ ?

Comment: I have corrected format of the question to some extent but you need to further correct it, because it seems like something that you are missing.

Comment: Note that, once you're on the complex plane, there are many paths from $0$ to $i$. In general, your path integral would need to specify how to go from $0$ to $i$. However, if your integrand satisfies the [Cauchy–Riemann equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Riemann_equations), the answer doesn't depend (much) on the path.

Answer (score 0):

This sort of notation is sometimes used when writing out contour integrals in the complex plane. You would evaluate it just as you propose, using the FTC, although you should note that what you're really doing is parameterizing the line from 0 to $i$ in the complex plane and then integrating along that line.

However, I'm a little skeptical that this integral is meaningful in the context of your differential equation. I'm far from an expert, and maybe integrals like this do come up in some situations, but I suspect you have a sign error somewhere that got you an imaginary number where you should have had a real.

Comment: I am sorry because the upper limit in Equation (2) is a real number 'a' which is greater than 1. Only in Equation (1) the upper limit is i=sqrt(-1). '▒' symbol has come up by mistake. In the equation that I was attempting to solve, the substitution yields the upper limit (of the integral, Equation (1) in my previous post) as either +i or -i.But I have chosen +i, for simplicity. I checked thoroughly, and haven't yet found any errors, I mean while arriving till this equation.

Comment: The reason why I had to chose this particular substitution, is because this is the only integrand which can be integrated, but again here like we see, we are getting complex upper limit. If I chose some other substitution, the integral doesn't seem to have a solution (the integrand becomes quite tricky), because it doesn't correspond to any known types of integral equations.However, I also do not have any software tools like Matlab, etc. to try solve those integral equations which I would arrive at with the other substitutions.

Comment: Anyways, so from the suggestions received for this integral equation, I think I can proceed with the solution of Equation (2) and substitute 'i=sqrt(-1)' in the place of 'a (which is any real number greater than 1)'. I hope that is going to be correct. Please do let me know if this is not correct. If this method is not correct, then I'll abort this differential equation problem.